# how to get in python real position of object that follows a NurbsPath?

Tags: python

I have an object following a NurbsPath (path is the parent of the tracker object)  and I am trying to print its position in each frame. but the "location" attribute always print the same value, doesn't matter in which position over the path the object is. 
I guess I am querying the wrong property.. this is the code I am using:

```
import bpy

sce = bpy.data.scenes[0]

obj = bpy.data.objects["tracker0"]
print(obj.location[0])

for i in range(0, 20):
    sce.frame_current = i
    print(obj.location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the global position of an object in blender use

```
obj.matrix_world.to_translation()
```

To change the frame use

```
scene.frame_set(frame)
```

...

```
import bpy

sce = bpy.context.scene

obj = bpy.data.objects["tracker0"]


for i in range(0, 20):
    sce.frame_set(i)
    print(obj.matrix_world.to_translation())
```